# Aligning equation using images with another equation centred on images

Tags: align, alignat

Basically, I have an equation that uses only images as the "variables" so-to-speak; it's just an illustration of image subtraction.  So what I would like to do is have this equation (that I have constructed using `\vcenter` with `\hbox` to align the image centres with the equation symbols) align the image centres to an equation above or below basically outlining what the images are, kind of like a caption for each image but in an equation format.

Below is the cdoe that will give the "image equation" but I can't seem to find a way to align another equation to the centres of each image. I've tried align and alignat but they I just can't get the syntax to work.

Code:

```
        \begin{equation*}\label{ImageSubtraction}
        \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{01ref}}} - \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{02raw}}} = \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{03subtract}}}
    \end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (EDITED)...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
{\centering\tabcolsep0pt
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{01ref}}} $&${}-{}$& 
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{02raw}}} $&${}={}$& 
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=.7cm,height=.7cm]{03subtract}}}$\\
$mx $&${}-{}$& 
$(-b) $&${}={}$& 
$y$
\end{tabular}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]